# Test if post parent NOT equals multiple ID's

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to test for multiple id's of post parents. currently i'm testing for post parent with the ID of 23 but I also want to test for parent ID of 1389. How do I do this?

```
<?php if($post->post_parent!==23){ ?>scale-with-grid<? } ?>
```

Comment: You're looking for the logical or operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `in_array` function for this:

```
if(!in_array($post->post_parent, array(23, 1389)) ...
```